# python: ImportError: No module named src.results

Tags: python, python-module, pythonpath

I have a working code given by my prof. I am asked just to learn to use it.
I am runing it on a remote `Ubuntu` machine, at uni, with `python 2.7`, the same server my prof uses and says it works for him.
Unfortunately when starting the `.py` file I get the following error:

```
$ python bks-cascade.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bks-cascade.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.results import *
ImportError: No module named src.results
```

Here are the first 5 lines:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import argparse

from src.results import *  # here it fails
```

So I googled and discovered I have to add that to my sys path and so i did:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:src"
```

and also
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:src/results"
and then:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

/home/bojanpoletan/Proj
/home/bojanpoletan/Proj/src/results
/home/bojanpoletan/Proj/src
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2015.1.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools-2015.1.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py-1.4.30-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dlib-19.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
```

then I tried again to run the program but still nothing.
Attached you can see the hierarchyof my project folder.
[Hierarchy of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d0lA.png)

Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: what about `from results import *` ?

Comment: Error: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bks-cascade.py", line 5, in <module>
    from results import *
  File "/home/bojanpoletan/Proj/src/results.py", line 14, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
ImportError: No module named seaborn`

Comment: That's a different error occurring in the module that you now successfully imported.

Comment: Yes, now i am trying to install it but getting some error. `pip2 install seaborn
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-fZgkYo/seaborn/setup.py", line 67, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("seaborn requires python >= 3.6.")
    RuntimeError: seaborn requires python >= 3.6.`
I must see if I can install it n

Comment: Are you running the program the same way? Have you tried running it as a module?

Comment: if you mean with `-m` then yes, it prompts the following error: `/usr/bin/python: No module named seaborn` an i can not install it on that machine as you can see it above. i am looking for a workaround, if you have any idea :)